# How to create a scheduled service in Flutter

Tags: service, flutter, dart, scheduled-tasks

How can you create a scheduled service in Flutter, which will be triggered at a specific time every day, and it will run some code? It needs to work for both Android and IOS and even if the app is terminated.

Comment: Is it required to run on the app? You could have that running on your server.

Comment: I need it to work even if the phone is offline, so it has to be a local service

Comment: You must run a background process for that

Comment: Yeah, but how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the [alarm manager package](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager).

A simple implementation of the same would look like below.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void doStuff() {
  print("do stuff every minute");
}

Future<void> main() async {
  final int periodicID = 0;

  // Start the AlarmManager service.
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();

  runApp(const Center(
      child:
      Text('See device log for output', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)));
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
      const Duration(minutes: 1), periodicID, doStuff,
      wakeup: true);
}
```

Comment: Will this work for IOS as well? And when the app is terminated either by user or OS?